# Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TableContinuationToken'

Tags: typescript, azure, eslint, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

According to the docs [link](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableService.html), when querying a table using **queryEntities**, the **continuationToken** can be passed in as **null** or **undefined** (Please use 'null' or 'undefined' if this is the first operation.)
However, that does not compile: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type **'TableContinuationToken'**.

Getting the error while running the server.
[image]

And this error is also caught by eslint.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got 3 workaround solutions to get it resolved.

1. use of **@ts-ignore**
   [image]
2. use **<any>** in front of **null**.
   [image]
3. use  **null as any**. This also recommended by Sonar Linting
   [image]

Both solutions are working and I am able to start the server.
[image]